# How to run multiple chained, variable dependent, pipes in Angular 2

Tags: angular

What I'm trying to achieve is to sort the array `users` according to the User's selection, and split the result into navigable pages of 20.

My template has a table that looks like this

```
<table>
   <thead>...</thead>
   <tbody>
            <tr
                *ngFor="let theUser of users | sort: [ sortField, sortAscending ] | paginate: [ pageNumber-1, pageSize ] ">
                <td>{{theUser.id}}</td>
                <td>{{theUser.attribute0}}</td>
                <td>{{theUser.attribute1}}</td>
                <td>{{theUser.attribute2}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

`paginate` outputs a section of the input table, `sort` sorts it according to given parameters. Both pipes were written by me, and work as expected individually.

The component changes the variables `sortField` and `sortAscending` in a function bound to clicks on the table header's cells, which calls this function based on the clicked cell:

```
   sortUsers(field:string): void{
    if(this.sortField==field){
      this.sortAscending=!this.sortAscending;
    }else{
      this.sortAscending=true;
      this.sortField=field;
    }
    this.detector.detectChanges();
  }
```

Where `detector` is an injected instance of `ChangeDetectorRef`.
Further, `pageNumber` is bound to a spinner with `[(ngModel)]`.

My problem is that when I click the table header cells, my pipe's log output indicates that only the first pipe has been invoked, and when I change the value of the spinner, only the second pipe gets invoked. The behavior I'm expecting is that both pipes get invoked.

**EDIT:** I worked around this particular case by incrementing `pageNumber`, calling `detectChanges`, then decrementing it and calling `detectChanges` again. I'd still like to know how to solve the general case.

**EDIT2:** [Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CvWZkAoUhGeRQQL5Pc12), related [bug report here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11138)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the bug report, the issue was that my sort was outputting a reference to the original array. Since the reference was not changing, change detection was interpreting the output as unchanged.

User vicb at GitHub offered the following solutions:

- Return a new array.

  - This is the correct solution for this particular use-case. `sort`'s output should be a significantly different array each time, so changing the array ref each time makes sense and communicates the change to Angular2 change detection.
- Mark the pipes as non-pures.

  - This would cause `paginate` to be run every change-detection round, i.e. every keystroke or mouse move. Might be acceptable but takes more processor cycles than the above.
- Trigger the change detection by hand on sort / paginate.

Comment: I am using Angular 5, I wrote pipes to sort and paginate. In my sort pipe, I return sortedArray.slice(0), which I think is returning a clone of the inputArray (after sorting), and hence the reference is changed. I used ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() in my component. Only paginate seems to work, but not sort. 

Sort and Paginate pipes for me are working individually, but when used together, only paginate seems to work.

Comment: On a separate note, I forgot making one of the pipes impure. Oops, thanks a lot. That helps. I am not even using ChangeDetectorRef now.